# Proving Statement with Diagonalizable Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

In Serge Lang’s Linear Algebra, a diagonalizable linear map is defined to be a linear map $F$ such that it has a basis $B$ where $M^B_B(F)$ is a diagonal matrix.

So the theorem I’ve been stumped on proving is stated on p.93 as follows:

> > Let V be a finite dimensional vector space over $K$, let $F:V\to V$ be a linear map, and let $M$ be its associated matrix relative to a basis $B$. Then $F$ (or $M$) can be diagonalized (in $K$) if and only if there exists an invertible matrix $N$ in $K$ such that $N^{-1}MN$ is a diagonal matrix.

I proved the forward direction but I have no idea how to start the proof for the backward direction. I am pretty confused because the theorem Lang stemmed off of to justify this theorem was that for bases $B,B’$ for $V$, and $F:V\to V$ a linear map, there exists invertible $N$ such that $M_{B’}^{B’}(F)=N^{-1}M^B_B(F)N.$ Not sure how to use this.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It might be helpful to specify the definitions: for many people, a matrix $M$ is diagonalisable if and only if $M = PDP^{-1}$ for some invertible matrix $P$ and diagonal matrix $D$. Is the definition of diagonalisable used in the book that there exists a basis $b_1, \ldots, b_n$ such that $F(b_i) = d_i b_i$ for some $d_i \in K$?

Comment: @Joppy The definition given is that $F$ is diagonalizable if there exists a basis $B$ in $V$ such that $M^B_B(F)$ is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: @Joppy I’ll add that to the original question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For linear transformation $F$ to be diagonalizable, it need to have a full set of eigenvectors. This is because, the eigenvectors corresponding to a linear transformation is always fixed and if we look at the action of a diagonal matrix on the corresponding basis vectors (we view action on a basis by left multiplication of the matrix with the correspo0nding basis matrix), it just scales the vectors. So, if a matrix can be written as $P^{-1}DP$, $D$ being a diagonal matrix, the basis has to be eigenvectors of $F$, and we get that $F$ has full set of eigenvectors, hence diagonalizable.